# Kotlin on Android: map a cursor to a list

Tags: android, functional-programming, kotlin

In Kotlin, What's the best way to iterate through an Android Cursor object and put the results into a list?

My auto-converted Java:

```
val list = ArrayList<String>()
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    list.add(getStringFromCursor(c))
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way? In particular, can it be done in a single assignment of a read-only list? E.g....

```
val list = /*mystery*/.map(getStringFromCursor)
```

... or some other arrangement, where the list is assigned fully-formed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is what I went with in the end, using `kotlin.sequences.generateSequence`...

```
val list = generateSequence { if (c.moveToNext()) c else null }
        .map { getStringFromCursor(it) }
        .toList()
```

My first attempt was a little shorter:

```
val list = (1 .. c.count).map {
    c.moveToNext()
    getStringFromCursor(c)
}
```

Both versions rely on the cursor initially being positioned before the first record (as a new cursor is). The second would throw if that wasn't the case, while the first would return a shorter list.

Comment: Hm, and what about the first item? I think this one will be better:
`fun Cursor.asSequence(): Sequence<Cursor> = generateSequence(seed = takeIf { it.moveToFirst() }) { takeIf { it.moveToNext() } }`

Comment: A fresh cursor is positioned before the first record, so the first c.moveToNext() will move to the first record.

Answer (score 4):

`Cursor`s are meant to be lazy so there is no obvious `map`. However [Anko](http://github.com/Kotlin/anko) (ANdroid KOtlin by JetBrains) does have an extension method to help you with mapping `Cursor`.

The method is called `Cursor.parseList(parser)`. [Here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/701bb6dd76830d9c24cf6578df750a9f3427b603/anko/library/static/sqlite/src/SqlParsers.kt) you can find full implementation of it. Usage should be straight-forward. And [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/doc/SQLITE.md#parsing-query-result) are some official docs on sqlite and parsing cursors with anko.

Comment: Anko looks useful. However, it doesn't seem to have a function that can send the cursor object to my existing `getStringFromCursor` function. It only sends an array or map of column values. As I'm hoping to convert my app to Kotlin gradually, that's a problem. (The source shows me how to write a suitable extension function, though, so thanks for that.)

Comment: I don't know how your `getStringFromCursor` looks like, but quite possibly it can be implemented as:
`cursor.parseList { it["column_name_with_string"] } `
or
`val COLUMN_INDEX = 2`
`cursor.parseList { it[COLUMN_INDEX] } `

Comment: Yes, the Anko way looks pretty nice, but in this case I'm rewriting test code and I'd like to test an existing function (which takes a cursor and returns a string for that record). Anko hides the cursor object, which means that I can't pass it to the existing function: It means I'd have to rewrite both things.

Comment: Actually, I think what was confusing me was that `parseList` takes a parser object not a function. I could do the following instead, which uses the cursor object from the enclosing scope, and (wastefully) ignores the column array created for each row: `c.asSequence().map { getStringFromCursor(c) }`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this extension:

```
fun <T> Cursor.toArrayList(block: (Cursor) -> T) : ArrayList<T> {
    return arrayListOf<T>().also { list ->
        if (moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                list.add(block.invoke(this))
            } while (moveToNext())
        }
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
val list = cursor.toArrayList { getStringFromCursor(it) }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own `map()` which checks against `isClosed()` and safely close the `Cursor` after iterating all over its rows like below:

```
fun <T> Cursor.map(f: (Cursor) -> T): List<T> {
  val items = mutableListOf<T>()
  use {
    while (!it.isClosed && it.moveToNext()) {
      items += f(it)
    }
  }
  return items.toList()
}
```

Sample usage:

```
val contacts = cursor.map { it.toContact() }
```

Comment: This will skip the first row, as it calls `moveToNext()` before processing it. It also requires that the caller invoke `moveToFirst()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to look at it

```
cursor.moveToFirst()
val list = generateSequence {
    cursor.moveToNext()
    getStringFromCursor(cursor)
}.take(cursor.count).toList()
```

Comment: Using `count` is generally discouraged. Depending on specific DB configuration, you may not know the exact count in advance or the real count might be much larger than you get (due to caching). The safest way is to use the result of `moveToNext()` method to determine whether you have reached the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your first suggestion is correct. You can't map cursor.

Comment: OK. I wasn't really expecting to be able to do so directly. I wondered whether there's a more idiomatic way (not necessarily using `map` -- I've updated the question to clarify).

Comment: It doesn't matter that you used `map`. You can't do that in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Rafols I created a small function to solve that problem, because I didn't like converting from an Array to an Object with Anko. Advantages of my solution: It closes the cursor automatically, it is `inline` therefore it has less performance impact and you can use the column names in your `parseRow` function.

```
private inline fun <T> getObjectListFromCursor(cursor: Cursor, parseRow: (Cursor) -> T): List<T> {
        return cursor.run {
            mutableListOf<T>().also { list ->
                if (moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        list.add(parseRow(this))
                    } while (moveToNext())
                }
                close()
            }
        }
    }
```

you call it like this:

```
val list = getObjectListFromCursor(c, this::getStringFromCursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help others.

```
        var list = ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>()

        if (c != null)
        {
          c.moveToFirst()
          do
          {
            val temp = HashMap<String, String>()
            temp.put("id", c.getString(0))
            temp.put("body", c.getString(1))
            temp.put("address", c.getString(2))
            list.add(temp)
          }
          while (c.moveToNext())
        }
```

Comment: "In particular, can it be done in a single assignment of a read-only list?" Your answer doesn't address this, and is more complicated than the auto-converted code.

Comment: I was stuck over the same issue but I haven't looked at the "single assignment of a read-only list" so this answer not related to you but this solved my problem so I posted it here it might help someone because I searched a lot and didn't found any solution.